# Extractability property in Zero Knowledge Discrete Log problems

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, provable-security

I am trying to construct a simulator and an extractor for a zero knowledge protocol. I just encountered [this text](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/How-To-Simulate-It-A-Tutorial-on-the-Simulation-Lindell/c031e9110e82b397e4f4dc24b802761ac6551ec9) that explains the construction of the simulator.

Does someone know of a similar text that explains extractor construction in depth? I need to construct the extractor and prove that it extracts with non negligible probability.